# Android Layout Densities folder

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen

I have the next problem:

I have a folder name layout (path: res/layout/...) that contains some activities.
I create another folder name layout-xhdpi (path: res/layout-xhdpi/...) with the same activities.
I added to the main activity inside layout-xhdpi a textView that shows "You enter in xhdpi".

The problem is that when i run the app in a Samsung S4 that is a xxhdpi, it opens the activity XHDPI, not enter to res/layout/...

Why is this happening?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, layout-xhdpi will be used for xhdpi devices and higher, unless you have other layouts for bigger dpi (e.g. layout-xxhdpi).
The default folder will be used for devices with lower resolution.

Comment: i have anither question. Im testing my app in a Samsung S4 and a Sony Xperia Z. Both have 1080 x 1920, 5'' screen, bothe xxhdpi. The problem is in sony xperia z the views are not in the wright position... why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Android selects the version of each resource that best matches the current device.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

In section "Screen pixel density (dpi)":

> Note: Using a density qualifier does not imply that the resources are
>   only for screens of that density. If you do not provide alternative
>   resources with qualifiers that better match the current device
>   configuration, the system may use whichever resources are the best
>   match.